# Paho-MQTT with Python3.8 throwing error: AttributeError: module 'socks' has no attribute 'HTTP'

Tags: python, mqtt, pythonanywhere, paho, socks

Hi Pythonanywhere fellows,

I'd like to subscribe to a TheThingsNetwork topic using the MQTT API: https://www.thethingsindustries.com/docs/integrations/mqtt/

The Api works fine for me using the paho-mqtt client: https://pypi.org/project/paho-mqtt/ My code looks as follows:

```
import context
import paho.mqtt.subscribe as subscribe
import time
import re
import json

while True:
    m = subscribe.simple(topics=['#'], hostname="eu1.cloud.thethings.network", port=1883, auth={'username':"mycrazyusername@ttn",'password':"mycrazypw"}, msg_count=2)
    for a in m:
        payload = json.loads(a.payload)
        print(payload)
```

I am receiving the following error that is related to the socks module:

```
 File "/home/Markovicz/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paho/mqtt/subscribe.py", line 262, in simple
    callback(_on_message_simple, topics, qos, userdata, hostname, port,
  File "/home/Markovicz/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paho/mqtt/subscribe.py", line 174, in callback
    client.connect(hostname, port, keepalive)
  File "/home/Markovicz/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 941, in connect
    return self.reconnect()
  File "/home/Markovicz/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1075, in reconnect
    sock = self._create_socket_connection()
  File "/home/Markovicz/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 3533, in _create_socket_connection
    proxy = self._get_proxy()
  File "/home/Markovicz/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 3494, in _get_proxy
    if self._proxy_is_valid(self._proxy):
  File "/home/Markovicz/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 3483, in _proxy_is_valid
    return check(p.get("proxy_type"), p.get("proxy_addr"))
  File "/home/Markovicz/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 3480, in check
    t in set([socks.HTTP, socks.SOCKS4, socks.SOCKS5]) and a)
AttributeError: module 'socks' has no attribute 'HTTP'
```

Do you have any ideas how to fix that?

This error has previously been reported here: https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/27492/

Comment: are you listening to a `topic` ?

Comment: @JayPatel yes I am, I changed the application_ID and password in the above example but it works well here on my Laptop with Python 3.6.

Comment: I have also tested python3.6 and there's still the same error.

Comment: It looks like versions of `PySocks` and `paho-mqtt` that you have installed are not compatible with one another.